# How to load new text widgets and polls into the sidebar without reloading the page?

Tags: ajax

We are creating a WordPress website page for the online broadcast of the conference. The page should work so that when a site visitor opens this page, the content on this page is automatically loaded without reloading the page itself.

In the right column there will be this chat "Wise Chat Pro".
In the central column there will be a video player to watch the broadcast from YouTube, and under it will be a block where you can ask the speaker of the conference a question and the questions themselves will automatically appear without reloading the page, as in this example: https: //themes.webberwebber. com / live-neutral / live-relation-directly-from-an-imporant-event /. How to implement this is understandable, using the comments on the page and automatically load them by ajax

The problem is that in the left column of the site, as well as at the bottom of the central column, when a new quote or survey is published, they are automatically loaded on the page, without reloading the page itself.

Is it possible to load new quotes and polls into the sidebar of the WordPress site without reloading the page? I would be very grateful for a hint in which direction to move and how this can be implemented.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. It sounds like you want to use WordPress's AJAX API and Javascript. I'm not all that strong on that topic but others are. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.